# Displaying a toast message for the selected tab in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

### I am trying to display a toast message on the screen

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    // TabSpec Names
        private static final String TAB1 = "Tab1";
        private static final String TAB2 = "Tab2";
        private static final String TAB3 = "Tab3";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

            // Inbox Tab
            TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB1);
            Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
            inboxSpec.setIndicator(TAB1);
            // Tab Content
            inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

            // Outbox Tab
            TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB2);
            Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
            PriceSpec .setIndicator(TAB2);
            PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

            // Profile Tab
            TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB3);
            Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
            DistanceSpec .setIndicator(TAB3); 
            DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
            tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
            tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 

            //Set the current value tab to default first tab
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

            //Setting custom height for the tabs
            final int height = 45;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = height;


        }
}
```

ScreenShot::

[image]

---

What i am trying to do ::

- Clearly we can see that there are three tabs namely `Tab1`, `Tab2`,
  `Tab3`
- When i click `Tab1` i should be able to display a toast as `Tab1` is clicked,
  similarly for `Tab2` & `Tab3`
- Basically we can see the toast message based on the selection where
  toast is fetching the text on the tab
- How to achieve this

Comment: where is you tablistener code

Comment: @ Raghunandan ..... What is a tablistener code ....( I am a newbie to android ).... only other classes i have are three different java classes for three different tab !

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated

Comment: Yes as @Raghunandan said its deprecated.Action bar is preferred.

Comment: @sush so it is not good to extend `TabActivity` which is what you have posted in your post and there is no explanation.

Comment: @NewBie don't use `TabActivity` its deprecated. read the docs has code snippets also http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: As learner i just provided solution. But as a developer i suggest wt ur suggesting.

Comment: @ Raghunandan ... thanks for the info ... i will keep this in mind.... i am a newbie so trying to understand how all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

// TabSpec Names
    private static final String TAB1 = "Tab1";
    private static final String TAB2 = "Tab2";
    private static final String TAB3 = "Tab3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB1);
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(TAB1);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

        // Outbox Tab
        TabSpec PriceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB2);
        Intent PriceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
        PriceSpec .setIndicator(TAB2);
        PriceSpec.setContent(PriceIntent);

        // Profile Tab
        TabSpec DistanceSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB3);
        Intent DistanceIntent = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
        DistanceSpec .setIndicator(TAB3); 
        DistanceSpec.setContent(DistanceIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(PriceSpec); 
        tabHost.addTab(DistanceSpec); 
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        //Set the current value tab to default first tab
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        //Setting custom height for the tabs
        final int height = 45;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = height;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = height;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = height;


    }
    @Override
public void onTabChanged(String arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

Comment: Okk thanks .... so if just tweaking the question .... if i just want to print the selected tab on log .... what line of code should i use .... is it .... Logd("TAB-VALUE", tabHost.getApplicationContext());

Comment: use on tabChange method. In that add this Logd("TAB-VALUE",arg0);

Comment: yes but ... what about my line ... will it be valid .... suppose i want to use the log value outside tabChangemethod ... so ?

Comment: yes it is valid. after  this line any where. TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a toast message to your fragment activities using the syntax:

```
Toast.makeToast(getBaseActivity(), "Your Message Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This way requires you to add a toast message to every fragment activity. It would be easier to use your TabListener and display a toast message during change. If you are unfamiliar with a tablistener you can view the developer docs from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html).

If you are having trouble identifying your tablistener just post your code please.